# Hive & RegexSerde returning just NULL

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to parse the following line for example using the RegexeSerde in Hive:

> 2011-07-22 20:34:51 808 8b1f27d094fb33ea - - - OBSERVED "unavailable"
>   http://www.4shared.com/  200 TCP_NC_MISS GET
>   text/javascript;charset=UTF-8 http dc413.4shared.com 80
>   /network/search-suggest.jsp ?search=2 KfZhNit2LHYqA==&format=jsonp jsp
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18)
>   Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18" 82.137.200.42 484 852 -

My table definition is this:

```
CREATE   external TABLE browsing_data_ext(
  cdate STRING,
  ctime STRING,
  time_taken STRING,
  c_ip STRING,
  cs_username STRING,
  cs_auth_group STRING,
  x_exception_id STRING,
  sc_filter_result STRING,
  cs_categories STRING,
  cs_Referer STRING,
  sc_status STRING,
  s_action STRING,
  cs_method STRING,
  rs_Content_Type STRING,
  cs_uri_scheme STRING,
  cs_host STRING,
  cs_uri_port STRING,
  cs_uri_path STRING,
  cs_uri_query STRING,
  cs_uri_extension STRING,
  cs_User_Agent STRING,
  s_ip STRING,
  sc_bytes STRING,
  cs_bytes STRING,
  x_virus_id STRING  )
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "([\\-0-9]*) ([\\:0-9]*) ([\\d]*) ([\\.a-z0-9]*) ([\\-a-z0-9]*) ([\\-a-z0-9]*) ([\\-a-z0-9]*) ([\\w]*) (\\\"[\\w]*\\\") ([\\.\\-\\=\\&:\\/\\?a-z0-9]*) ([\\d]*) ([\\_\\w]*) ([\\w]*) ([\\/\\w]*) ([\\w]*) ([\\.\\w]*) ([\\d]*) ([\\.\\-\\=\\&:\\/\\?a-z0-9]*) ([\\.\\-\\=\\&:\\/\\?a-z0-9]*) ([\\.\\w]*) (\\\"[\\w\\W]*\\\") ([.:a-z0-9]*) ([\\d]*) ([\\d]*) ([\\-a-z0-9]*)",
  "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s %10$s %11$s %12$s %13$s %14$s %15$s %16$s %17$s %18$s %19$s %20$s %21$s %22$s %23$s %24$s %25$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/hdfs/Data'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="6");
```

I've tested it in rubular and few other Regex validation tools which all pass but when I'm selecting from the table I'm receiving just NULL values;

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I had to read a long log file and the procedure to solve it was:

Create the regex with this 
1) https://regex101.com/#java

2) Replace only the "\w" "\s" and "\w" for "\w"

Inside each parentheses I used "+" not "*" for referring to "one or more of a".

Without the 2) the result was the whole line with NULL values but after adding the double "\" to all the special characters the test was successfully parsed.

Comment: * Replace only the "\w" and "\s" for "\\s" and "\\w"